# initWithCoder: not visible in NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nscoding

I have an interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Picture : NSObject;

@property (readonly) NSString *filepath;
- (UIImage *)image;

@end
```

and implementation:

```
#import "Picture.h"

#define kFilepath @"filepath"

@interface Picture () <NSCoding> {
    NSString *filepath;
}

@end


@implementation Picture
@synthesize filepath;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return self;

}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:filepath forKey:kFilepath];
}

- (UIImage *)image {
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
}

@end
```

I get error: **ARC issue - No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector' initWithCoder:'**

Is there something different about NSCoding when using ARC?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing different between ARC and manual reference counting. `NSObject` doesn't conform to `NSCoding` and therefore doesn't supply `-initWithCoder:` or `-encodeWithCoder:`. Just don't call through to the superclass implementations of those methods.

```
- (id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [aCoder decodeObject: filepath forKey: kFilepath];
    }
    return self;
}
```